# Import all modules from a directory at once [NODE]

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
MyApp
├── main.js
└── modules
    ├── a.js
    ├── b.js
    ├── c.js
    ├── d.js
    ├── e.js
```

In my NodeJS app, how can I import all my custom modules (a,b,c,d,e) in my main.js file at once?

I have long list of modules and I dont want to import them all separately.

Answer (score 3):

Create an `index.js` in the `modules/` folder:

```
const a = require('./a')
const b = require('./b')
const c = require('./c')
const d = require('./d')
const e = require('./e')

module.exports = {
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
  e
}
```

Then just import the module in `main.js`:

```
const modules = require('./modules')
modules.a
```

Alternatively you could loop through the directory and dynamically import each module.

Answer (score 2):

You can  dynamically import each module.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs
  .readdirSync(`${__dirname}/modules`)
  .filter(file => (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach((file) => {
    require(`./modules/${file}`)
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use manual way to import all modules in a directory

```
var allModules = {};
require('fs').readdirSync(__dirname + '/modules/').forEach(function(file) {
  if (file.match(/\.js$/) !== null && file !== 'index.js') {
    var name = file.replace('.js', '');
    allModules[name] = require('./modules/' + file);
  }
});
// allModules.a(params)
```

or you can use this library for this case [require-dir](https://github.com/aseemk/requireDir)

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
var modulesPackage = requireDir('./modules');
// modulesPackage contains 
//{
//  a: require("./modules/a"),
//  b: require("./modules/b")
//}
```

The lib has a tip: If you want to require() the same directory in multiple places, you can do this in the directory itself! Just make an index.js file with the following:

```
module.exports = require('require-dir')();   // defaults to '.'
```

Where you want to use a package in modules:

```
var mds = require('./modules');
// mds.a(params) .....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const modulesPath = './modules';
const modulesList = fs.readdirSync(modulesPath);
modulesList.forEach(modulePath => require(path.resolve(modulesPath, modulePath)));
```