# NodeJS Express overlapping routers

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, routes

I've encountered some bug(?) while building a NodeJS express API. Apparently some endpoints overlap each other which means I can't reach them, the request doesn't end until it timeouts.

ex:

```
const load_dirs = (dirs, filename) => {
    const router_files = readdirSync(`./${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith(`${filename}.js`));
    router_files.forEach(file => {
        const { 
            getUsers, getUser, addUser, editUser, removeUser, loginUser, updateUserStatus
        } = require(`../${dirs}/${file}`);

        router
            .route('/')
            .get(cors(corsOptions), getUsers)
            .post(cors(corsOptions), addUser);

        router
            .route('/login')
            .post(cors(corsOptions), loginUser);
        
        router
            .route('/:userId')
            .get(cors(corsOptions), getUser)
            .post(cors(corsOptions), editUser)
            .put(cors(corsOptions), removeUser);

        router
            .route('/:userId/status')
            .post(cors(corsOptions), updateUserStatus);
    });
}

['methods'].forEach(e => load_dirs(e, 'users'));

module.exports = (router);
```

If the login method is above the get user by Id, i can't reach the user by Id or vice versa.
And since this is a somewhat unique way of using node (haven't found anyone else who uses it), i can't figure it out...

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Edit 1:

As requested in the comments, i leave here the `getUsers` method:

```
exports.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
    try  {
        await new Promise(async (resolved, rejected) => {
            let conn;

            try {
                conn = await db.pool.getConnection();
                const result = await conn.query(`
                    SELECT * FROM users
                `)

                .then((resp) => {                    
                    if (!resp.length) {
                        res
                            .status(200)
                            .json({ success: true, message: general.noResults });
                        resolved(resp);
                        return;
                    }

                    const data = resp;

                    res
                        .status(200)
                        .json({ success: true, utilizadores: data });
                    resolved(resp);
                })

                .catch ((err) => {
                    if (mode() === 'development' || mode() === 'test') console.log(`Error: ${ err }.`);
                    res
                        .status(400)
                        .json({ success: true, message: general.badRequest });
                    rejected(err);
                })
            } catch (err) {
                if (mode() === 'development' || mode() === 'test') console.log(`Error: ${ err }`);
                res
                    .status(400)
                    .json({ success: false, message: general.badRequest });
                rejected(err);
            } finally {
                if (conn) {
                    conn.end();
                }
            }
        })

        .then((message) => {
            if (mode() === 'development' || mode() === 'test') console.log(message);
        })

        .catch((err) => {
            if (mode() === 'development' || mode() === 'test') console.log(err);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        if (mode() === 'development' || mode() === 'test') console.log(`Error: ${ err }.`);
        res
            .status(400)
            .json({ success: false, message: general.badRequest });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure:

```
      router
        .route('/:userId')
        .get(cors(corsOptions), getUser)
        .post(cors(corsOptions), editUser)
        .put(cors(corsOptions), removeUser);
```

Creates a wildcard route that matches ANY http request with a top level path such as:

```
/abc
/xxx
/123
```

So, when you go through the first iteration of your loop and create the first one of these top level wildcard routes, it will take precedence over any other top level route that is added to the router after it.  Thus, it will take the requests for the future iterations of the loop that try to define handlers for `/login`.

---

But, this whole model is busted.  Even if you remove the wildcard route, it's not the only problem.  Since each iteration of your loop is just defining the exact same routes over and over again, the routes defined in the first iteration of the loop will take precedence over all the other routes in subsequent iterations of the loop.

Your subsequent iterations of the loop need to be defining different routes.  If we remove all the complication you have here and just show:

```
app.get("/login", someHandler1);
app.get("/login", someHandler2);
```

Then, the second definition will never get a chance to see the `/login` route unless someHandler1 happens to decide to not send a response and instead call `next()` to pass control on down the chain.

So, the whole model of defining the same routes over and over again in a loop seems flawed.  In addition, I would tend to avoid a top level wildcard route because it creates conflicts with other top level routes as you grow your features.  Instead, either do `/id/:userId` or define a regex that matches only a top level userId, but leaves room for other top level routes that won't match that regex.

---

To come up with a solution, I'd have to understand better what exactly you're trying to do when you have multiple files with all the same exported request handlers and all the same route paths.  On the surface, that just doesn't make sense to me.  You don't handle the exact same incoming request multiple times.  You handle it once so there needs to be one piece of code (not N pieces of code) that handle any given route.

---

FYI, here's a simplified version of your `getUsers()` function.  You don't need the wrap in a promise and don't need so much duplicated error handling:

```
exports.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
    let conn;
    try {
        conn = await db.pool.getConnection();
        const result = await conn.query(`SELECT * FROM users`);
        if (!result.length) {
            res.json({ success: true, message: general.noResults });
        } else {
            res.json({ success: true, utilizadores: results });
        }
    } catch(err) {
        if (mode() === 'development' || mode() === 'test') console.log(`Error:`, err);
        res.status(400).json({ success: true, message: general.badRequest });
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            conn.end();
        }
    }
});
```

**Summary of changes:**

1. Remove `await new Promise()` wrapper as that is not necessary
2. Remove `.then()` and `.catch()` so we're only using `await` and `try/catch`
3. Put all error handling in one catch block
4. Coalesce all errors handlers into one place
5. Fix logging of error object
6. Remove `.status(200)` since 200 is already the default.

FYI, I would argue that you do want to log errors, even in production, not only in development.  If you start having problems in the deployed, production server, you will want to have log info that tells you what the actual internal errors are.  So, I'd suggest you remove the `if` that only logs errors in development or test.

Comment: I missed the route definitions inside the loop the first time I looked at OP's code.

Comment: I've been using this method since I started my discordjs bot... it seemed a good way to avoid having an app.js with if else structure with all the commands and logic...

Comment: I'm trying to invert the routers order and add the `/id/` parameters as to avoid the matches and getting the request pending

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 -  The fundamental question here is why are you defining multiple routes all with the same path?  You have never explained that and that is unusual.  Perhaps if you show the code inside these routes, that would help to understand.  And, the wildcard route creates a general problem as you want to modify your system going forward.  What if someone creates a userID that conflicts with some future path you want to use in  your design?  Are you calling `next()` inside your routes to allow further routing?

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - Yes, you could define the wildcard routes in their own separate loop so they were always after all the other routes.  But, this is still a very weird architecture and I'm quite sure there is a better way to do this, but you'd have to show us the code inside the route handlers for us so we can see how a give route handler is deciding whether to handle the route or call `next()` to continue routing before we can offer ideas on a better way to implement this.

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - Also, if your server is just not responding to some routes, that means that it matches a route handler, but the route handler didn't either send a response OR call `next()` to continue routing and that has nothing to do with this architectural discussion - that's just the responsibility of any route handler.  They all have to either send a response or call `next()`.

Comment: as @kevintechie said, I'm trying to dynamically load the files, inside the methods files i only have the methods defines as such: `exports.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => { logic ... }`, and no, I've only used `next()` on middleware functions like token verification and whatnot...

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - If you're not calling `next()` in a route handle, then how you do you ever expect the second route handler registered for the same route such a `/login` to ever get called.  The whole scheme just seems entirely wrong.  No routes for a given path except the first one registered will ever get called.  Express calls the first route that matches a given path and does not call any others unless you call `next()`.  I'm trying to help here, but you're hiding too much of what you're trying to do here in order to be able to help efficiently.

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - Do you understand that if two route handlers are registered for the same path or matching wildcard (like you are doing in your loop), that Express will only call the first one that matches unless you call `next()` inside that first matching route handler which then tells Express to look for the next matching route handler?  If you don't send a response or call `next()`, then everything stops and the request will just eventually time out.

Comment: what more code is needed? @jfriend00

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - I'd suggest adding the code for each `getUsers()` method (or at least two of them).

Comment: original question Edit #1 @jfriend00, all my methods follow this structure

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - So, that `getUsers()` implementation eats any route that it matches (it sends a response and never calls `next()`) which is the usual design for a route handler.  So, there's no point in ever having this registered for the same path as any other path.  We're back to the same fundamental question.  Why are you assigning multiple route handlers to the exact same path?  That's useless because only the first one will ever get called.

Comment: like i said to @kevintechie i've changed the code a bit, and moved the routers definition outside the loop, and still inverted their order and added `/id/`like you suggested, is it still made to fail? works so far i guess

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - Also, that `getUsers()` code could be written in about half the number of lines of code.  Don't need the `await new Promise()`, can massively simplify the error handling.

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - Well, then I don't know what I'm trying to help with any more if we're not working on the code in your question.

Comment: again... the initial idea was to have the methods all in separate files... so getUsers() would be getUsers.js, loginUser() would be loginUser.js and so on... unable to achieve that, i went with the best next thing i guess

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - Is this question done now?  Or, is there something you're still trying to get help with?  FYI, it wouldn't be hard to get `getUsers()` in `getUsers.js` and have it dynamically loaded that way, but if you want to discuss that, please write a new question and drop me a comment on that question because that's not what this question describes at all.

Comment: I'll experiment some more, and if need help i'll make a new question if needed

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - I added a simplified `getUsers()` implementation to the  end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, fyi the promise was there because i had to handle files and array bytes, but since then i moved them somewhere else, i'll remove promises from where they are not needed

Answer (score 1):

The loop is the problem. I'm guessing that you're trying to set up a route per file. You don't need to do this because you can use route parameters to substitute userId in your file access code.

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use(router);

const port = 3000;

const render1 = (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Render 1 says: hello world`);
}

const render2 = (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Render 2 says: logging in user...`);
}

const render3 = (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Render 3 says: reading user data from file ./userdata/${req.params.userId}.json`);
}

const render4 = (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Render 4 says: User ${req.params.userId} is logged in.`);
}

router.route('/').get(render1);

router.route('/login').get(render2);

router.route('/:userId').get(render3);

router.route('/:userId/status').get(render4);


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Actually, I'm setting all methods in one file as defined in the function `['methods'].forEach(e => load_dirs(e, 'users'))`, 'methods' is the folder where I store all the methods for the project... and 'users' is the actual file with the methods... so i loop throught the methods folder to find the `users.js` and when it does it imports all the defined methods, the same goes for the routers... in my app.js I have a loop to read the routers files.

Comment: The problem, as @jfriend00 pointed out, is that the routes should not be in the loop.

Comment: `router_files.forEach(file => { routers = require('../${dirs}/${file}'); });` and define the routers outside right?

Comment: Now that I understand what you're trying to accomplish (dynamically load route modules), there's more problems with your code. You don't want to put the spread of your route handler functions inside the loop either. You want to load them into an object and then access them with their name (e.g: routeHandler.getUsers, etc.) or spread your routeHandler object to the names. This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987464/import-all-modules-from-a-directory-at-once-node) should give you some pointers.

Comment: i parttially done that... only thing remaining is the `loadDirs()` function... the initial idea was to have a folder with the method name like `user` and inside `user` i would have the methods separated into different files, one for get, one for post and so on...

Comment: You might be making this more complex than it needs to be. I'm not sure that dynamically loading the routes is necessary unless you're using some automated tool to generate them and then restarting the app to expose them in the app. It is a good idea to organize your route handlers in folders according to whatever you want (by entity, route, http method etc) when things get complicated. However, just statically require or import them because you only need to code this once and when you add a new route, it doesn't save much effort to do it manually.