# How to use JSON files with createI18n in Vue

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vuejs3, vue-i18n

If I have a Vue project with a `main.js` file that looks like this:

```js
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './styles/main.scss'
import App from './App.vue'

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  fallbackLocale: 'en',   
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  messages: {
    en: {
    sample:{
      item1: 'hello world'
    }
  }} // set locale messages
});

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(i18n)
app.mount('#app')
```

How can I edit this so that the messages object uses my JSON translation files? Basically, I have translation files in my `locale` folder, and some examples are `en-US.json` and `fr-FR.json`.

So instead of hardcoding the transaltions directly inside of the messages object, I'd like to use my locale folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. The below code will load locale files from whatever path you specify in the `loadPath` option and uses the new `i18next-http-backend` since the `i18next-xhr-backend` was deprecated. And this code will auto detect the language and switch to the correct language if you locale file names have a structure like this: `en-US.json`, `en-PH.json`, `es-MX.json`, etc.

```
import i18next from 'i18next'
import I18NextVue from 'i18next-vue'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import i18nextHttpBackend from 'i18next-http-backend'

i18next.use(i18nextHttpBackend).use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    detection: {
      caches: false
    },
    fallbackLng: {
      default: ['en-US']
    },
    whitelist: [
      'en',
      'en-PH',
      'en-US',
      'es-MX'],
    backend: {
      loadPath: 'src/locales/{{lng}}.json'
    },
    load: 'currentOnly',
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
    saveMissing: true,
    saveMissingTo: 'all'
  });

export default function (app) {
  app.use(I18NextVue, { i18next })
  return app
}
```

And then use it by having this code in your `main.js`:

```
const app = createApp(App)
i18next(app)
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to create a separate folder for translation files, for example - `locales`. In this folder, you can store your json files for each target language.

`src/locales` directory content example:

```
- index.js
- en.json
- fr.json
- uk.json
```

`src/locales/index.js`:

```js
import en from "./en.json";
import fr from "./fr.json";
import uk from "./uk.json";

export const languages = {
  en: en,
  fr: fr,
  uk: uk,
};
```

`src/main.js`:

```js
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import { createApp } from "vue";

import "./styles/main.scss";
import App from "./App.vue";

import { languages } from "@/locales";

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  messages: languages
});

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(i18n);
app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: So I guess its impossible to code it to where I don't have to keep adding import statements each time I add a new language?

Comment: @mcool it will be a bit hacky solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987464/import-all-modules-from-a-directory-at-once-node. 

It's better to have more control and the possibility to enable exactly those languages you need. Some translation files might be untranslated and in case of explicit imports, you can allow these languages when it will be fully translated or proofreaded.